# NextExecution time with quartz definition fails when date if the end of the month

Tags: scala, cron, quartz

Currently, I have a cron job scheduling for every minute but once the date is the end of the month, the `nextExecution` method fails to provide the proper date.

```
test("check execution times") {
// make sure the execution times are correct
val expression = "0 * * ? * * *" // every minute (the top of the minute)
val currentTime = "2019-12-31T00:00:00.000Z" // get current time
val expectedNextExecution = "2019-12-31T00:01:00.000Z" // get current time
val cron = new CronParser(CronDefinitionBuilder.instanceDefinitionFor(CronType.QUARTZ)).parse(expression)
val executor = ExecutionTime.forCron(cron)
val actualNextExecution = executor.nextExecution(DateTime.parse(currentTime)).toString // call nextExecution which should give us the next top of the minute
// check if nextExecution has correct next execution time
assert(actualNextExecution == expectedNextExecution, "Wrong execution time")
}
```

**Results :**

```
Expected :"20[19-12-31T00:01]:00.000Z" 
Wrong execution time Actual   :"20[20-01-01T00:00]:00.000Z"
```

Comment: have you tried `"0 * * * * * *"`

Comment: what version of cron-utils and joda-time are you using?

Comment: "0 * * * * * *" is not an acceptable expression.

Comment: @asanand that was the issue. cron-utils was version 4.1 and they are now on 9.0.2 haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this was updating my cron-utils version.

Previously on:
4.1.0

Issue was fixed on:
9.0.2

Thank you